# Qt link library (C++ mix with objective C) error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, qt

1. I am using Qt to build UI Application,
2. The Qt application supposed to link to a static library (.a file)
3. The library is written by C++ and Objective C (*.mm) files.
4. I setup the Qt project file and linked the static library, but Qt Creator always gets linking error, and error is related with the function implement on *.mm which locates in the static library.

   ---

Question:
The Qt application how to link the library? 
that's pure C++ application (Qt application) link to static library with C++ and ObjectiveC mixed (.a file).

---

update: link error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QTCaptureDevice", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libmyapi.a(myTestFunction_mac.o)
  "_QTMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
      myTestFunction() in myapi.a(myTestFunction_mac.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp] Error 1
14:38:06: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project myApp (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 clang 64bit)
```

1. Qt5.1 with clang, support C++11
2. static library myapi.a, built by Xcode4.6 without error. Only one file is myTestFunction_mac, using QTKit framework.
3. myApp links myapi.a, but the myTestFunction_mac.mm implantation file has linking error.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `QTKit` framework to your app target.

**Xcode 4**
Click on the project in the browser pane to the left.
Click on the target under Targets.
Click on the Summary tab.
Expand Linked Frameworks and Libraries if not expanded.
Click on the + icon and type QTKit into the search box and add QTkit.

**Xcode 3**
Right click on the project.
Select Add-->Existing Frameworks.
Add QTkit.

Comment: in my api library, I built without error via xcode, and QTkit also added. The error is given by Qt Creator.

Comment: it's right, I need to link QTKit framework to my Qt application via QtCreator as well.